# TypeError: Property is undefined | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React so this questions is probably very basic, but I'd like some help.

All of the sudden Eslint started shouting at me because of `no-restricted-globals`, so I began to fix those errors. However, I got this classical error just now `TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined`, and here's the code:

```
import React from 'react'

export default props => {
  const url = ['#'].concat(props.to).join('/')
  const { location } = this.props
  return (
    <a
      href={url}
      onClick={props.onClick}
      className={location.hash.indexOf(url) === 0 ? 'active' : undefined}
    >
      {props.children}
    </a>
  )
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone explained why `location` is undefined, I just can't get that. Thanks for reading everyone!

Comment: should be `const { location } = props` not `this.props`

Comment: Wow thanks man! Now `hash` is undefined haha

Comment: Did you pass location in as props?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
import React from 'react'

    export default props => {
      const url = ['#'].concat(props.to).join('/')
      const location= this.props.location?this.props.location:[]
      return (
        
          {props.children}
        
      )
    }
```

Hope This might run properly!